# Find the following probabilities for a standard normal distribution $P(|Z| > 2.05)$

Tags: statistics

I have

- $P(|Z| > 2.05)$
- $P(-2.05 < Z < 2.05)$
- $P(Z < 2.05) - P(Z < -2.05)$
- $0.9798 - 0.0202$

and got my answer to be $0.9596$ but it seems off. I do not know where I missed a step. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You made an error in step 2:

$P(|Z|>2.05) = P(Z > 2.05) + P(Z< -2.05) = 2P(Z<-2.05) = .0404$ (by symmetry)

What you calculated was $P(|Z|<2.05)$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @user102156 you’re welcome — you can mark it as accepted if you don’t need additional answers